# SQL Import from CSV Change Characters

Tags: sql-server, utf-8, import-from-excel

I have a problem where I'm importing a CSV file using the SQL import wizard but the values being imported get changed after this process completes which I'm not sure why this is happening. I have selected the code page as UTF-8 and I can see that the values are being displayed correct here as this is a column which includes Spanish translation:

[image]

Once the process completes I can see that SQL is showing these completely wrong as you can see below:

[image]

How can I get it imported to keep the original Spanish translation?

- My database collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS and this can't be changed.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this might be related to CSV file export as I had just changed to rather export to Txt file and this imported correct and all is as per the info passed so not really sure but it's all good now. Thanks anyways!